# onClickListener never called when used with timePicker

Tags: android

```
    timePicker = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.tijd);
    timePicker.setOnClickListener(this);


    klaar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.klaar);
    klaar.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Does anyone know why only the Button triggers an onClick? The setOnClickListener on the timePicker doesn't seem to be working

edit: onclicklistener added, my main class implements onClickListener

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d("temp", "View clicked");



}
```

Comment: How does your `onClick(View v)` method look like?

Comment: I added it to the beginpost...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What click are you trying to capture? There are several views inside a TimePicker; looking [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TimePicker.html), TimePicker has an `OnTimeChangedListener` you can use, which seems more like what you would want. I imagine you could do `timePicker.setClickable(true)` to set the entire view to be clickable, but I don't think that would give the results you're looking for. Alternatively, take a look at the [`TimePickerDialog`](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-timepicker.html) example to see an example adapting a TimePicker into a dialog with a Set and Cancel button using an `OnTimeSetListener`.

Comment: Sorry to steal your thunder. :P

Comment: No worries, I had some jazz about "You probably don't want the whole TimePicker" clickable... As long as he's steered in the right direction.

Comment: I have a timepicker with setEnabled to false and I want to setEnabled(true) when the user taps the timepicker

Answer (score 0):

First comment is sensible. We can't answer you until we read onClick() method. But I can suggest you to implement click listeners in separate methods:

```
timePicker = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.tijd);
timePicker.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // method for timePicker
    }
});


klaar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.klaar);
klaar.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // method for button
    }
});
```